# Swift; Initialization of immutable value was never used

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I have this simple piece of `Swift` code:

```
let message = "This is a test"

if message.range(of:"test") != nil {
    let message = "Changed string"
}

print(message)
```

What I want to do: If string `message` contains the string `test`, change it to `Changed string`. Else keep it unchanged.

I'm getting the following warning:

> Initialization of immutable value 'message' was never used; consider
>   replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it

for line

```
let message = "Changed string"
```

Also, printed output is still `This is a test` instead of expected `Changed string`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don’t use `let` within the conditional block as it has already been declared. Also, it should be `var` anyway so you can change it.

Comment: As @Chris said, it's variable scope. Using `let` inside the `if` statement means you are actually declaring a *second* variable, not replacing the value of the first.

Comment: `message.range(of:"test").map { _ in message = "Changed string" }` ;D (given, naturally, that `message` is mutable: `var message = "This is a test"`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want it to change it, you should be making it a variable and using the same variable.

```
var message = "This is a test"

if message.range(of:"test") != nil {
    message = "Changed string"
}

print(message)
```

Answer (score 6):

So, a few people have already given you reasonable, technically correct answers, but i'd like to explain:

- declaring a value as `let` means that it is a constant i.e. immutable
- you are getting the warning because instead of modifying the value as you intended, you are redeclaring it within the scope of the if statement. in order to declare a mutable variable, we use `var` i.e.:

`var message = "This is a test"`

- a more appropriate API for this conditional might be [contains](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1414563-contains), because it is locale-unaware and returns `Bool`, rather than having to convert an `NSRange` to `Bool` by testing against != nil

Given the above, the final code would be as follows:

```
var message = "This is a test"

if message.contains("test") {
    message = "Changed string"
}

print(message)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Good to mention `contains`, but not that the `message` immutable within the scope of the `if` statement is not a re-declaration, per se, but rather a declaration of a new immutable (which could just as well be a mutable) shadowing the one from the scope one level up. A re-declaration, on the other hand, would yield an error, in this context.

Comment: I mean, at the risk of getting a little lost in the weeds here, you are right regarding the original scope: in that context, it is not a redeclaration. However, within the scope of the conditional, if you declare a variable with the same name, then I would consider that a redeclaration of the variable, since you can no longer access the previous variable within that scope.

Comment: It might be nit-picking, but I'm just trying to advice the correct use of the grammar here: shadowing or name masking (from a new variable) is not a redeclaration. The former refers to declaring a _new_ variable in a given scope such that it overshadows (by name masking) another variable declared at an outer scope. The latter, a redeclaration, on the other hand, refers to the act of (most of the time: erroneously) redeclaring a given variable. This is usually results in an error, e.g. _"Invalid redeclaration of <symbol>"_.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4 Implementation**

Here is the simplest way I could solve this problem.

```
var message1 = "This is a test"
var message2 = "This is a"

print(message1.contains("test") ? "Changed String" : message1) //"Changed String"
print(message2.contains("test") ? "Changed String" : message2) //"This is a"
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two variables called message in your code. One is the inner variable with "Changed string". The other, outer one has value "This is a test". So, if you want change the variable just declare it with `var`.

If your code was like:

```
let message = "This is a test"

if message.range(of:"test") != nil {
    let message = "Changed string"
    print (message)
}

print(message)
```

You'll get this output:

`"Changed string"
 "This is a test"`

This is because the inner variable didn't change the outer variable. 
In the inner you just declare and don't use it. The warning is there just to advise you that you have one unused variable.

Instead of this double `let`, you could declare:

```
var message = "This is a test"

if message.range(of:"test") != nil {
    message = "Changed string"
}

print(message)
```

as Rakesha Shastri answered.